# Performance gains from an image-less web design

Tags: performance, css

As browsers are finally starting to agree on CSS3, many web developers are rubbing their hands in excitement over their new, image-less web designs. They're clean. They're scaleable. They're powerful.

With border-radii, box-shadows, font-faces and the like, now we can convert our designer's beautiful design into lines of code, instead of packing our pages with img tags.

**Two related questions:**

- Is there a point when the stylesheet(s) get so large that they actually [negatively] affect performance to a noticeable degree?
- In a web application with lots of icons (in the range of 16px to 48px size), how noticeable would the performance boost be by using an icon font?

Comment: A text file with about 2500 lines of (uncompressed) CSS would still only be about 100kb. There might be potential performance issues if CSS3 animations are used on many elements simultaneously, but that has nothing to do with the file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a point when the stylesheet(s) get so large that they actually [negatively] affect performance to a noticeable degree?**

It's just common sense really. If your stylesheet(s) become quite large then that will have just as negative an effect as having lots of images. In general terms a stylesheet (with lots of CSS3 and fancy bits) will be faster to download than a load of images.

I'd recommend taking it case-by-case and deciding whether CSS or images provides the better solution taking into account download speeds, browser support requirements, desktop vs mobile and so on.

**In a web application with lots of icons (in the range of 16px to 48px size), how noticeable would the performance boost be by using an icon font?**

Unless you were talking about hundreds/thousands of icons then there really isn't going to be a hugely noticeable difference in performance. Remember with icon fonts you're also probably having the user download some custom fonts.

Again it's really a case of using what is best for the current project.

I don't think there is a definitive answer to your question but hopefully what I've said clears it up a little for you.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that it'd probably come down particular cases. I'll do some more digging in the code to see if it'll actually make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "point", and performance is not related so much to the size as it's related to the style rules themselves.  The main issues I've seen are related to CSS gradients (especially radial gradients).  This was a year or so back, but I remember testing some mobile devices with some mixture of gradients and on (webkit) mobile devices, the web page's display was notably lagging. Removing the gradients and adding images removed the lag. Now, for all I know, most devices now may have newer webkit display engines which might fix that issue, but I do think it's still a valid point to consider.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the CSS files does affect performance in a few cases. If the CSS is especially large, it will cause some issues. But as someone else mentioned, it is text, so its probably pretty small file. But if that CSS is split across many files, that becomes a bigger issue. I have seen some sites with 10-20 css files, all located on a single server. Depending on the browser, it can only open 2-6 (maybe 8) connections at a time to each server. If you have 10 css files, plus another 10 js, plus 100 other assets, thats going to take a relatively long time to open and close the various connections. One way to solve this is to concatenate the CSS files as part of your development process. Some tools that do this that I like are Yeoman or Codekit. Those tools will also automatically minify the CSS as well making the one file they generate that much smaller.

Using an icon font is good because they are scalable and use a single file. As you zoom in on a page, the icons continue to look great, while the pngs you might use look terrible. The icon font is also one file, so for the same reason as above, its one file versus 10s-100s. If you do need to use PNG files for some parts that are not icons, look into using sprites, often referred to as CSS Sprites. This is a technique for combining several images into a single png file, which can then be used on the site with some creative CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on concatenators. Those will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of CSS is that the styles cascade upon one another. Extremely large style sheets would lead me to believe the CSS is not written properly and therefore not cascading down. That being said, I suppose its possible have large properly cascading style sheets in which case I would recommend using a minifier to eliminate white space and compress your code to make the load time faster.

As for the icons are concerned, you could possible create a sprite (a collection of multiple images) and then use CSS positioning to only show the icon you needed. In this way the server would fetch only one large image instead of a lot of smaller images. Granted it, the one image is larger than the others, but nothing kills load time and slows a page's performance than a ton of fetch requests by a server for images.